# CreateNdefMessageCallback conflict with ContentProvider permissions

Tags: android, nfc

I write a program provider a provider for another apps of our company. The provider need a permission to access the data.

We also have a interface need use NFC send json data to another devices.

When we access the provider in **CreateNdefMessageCallback.createNdefMessage** like

```
    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        Context context = this;

        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Uri.parse("content://demo/data-lists"),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        // FIXME Strange: Will never goes here ...
        mMessage = getMessage(cursor);

        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[] {
                        createMimeRecord(mMimeType, mMessage.getBytes())
                });
        return msg;
    }
```

There is very strange, we never get a cursor until remove the permission.

### Permission Declear

```
<permission
    android:name="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION"
    android:label="@string/provider_label"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

### Request permision

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />
```

### Provider permission declear

```
    <provider
        android:name=".provider.DemoProvider"
        android:authorities="demo"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:permission="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />
```

Currenty the provider and the NFC-send activity in the same application and read the provider data will but the NFC callback.
And if I remove the permission for the provider, this will work fine.
like the

### Provider without permission

```
    <provider
        android:name=".provider.DemoProvider"
        android:authorities="demo"
        android:multiprocess="true"/>
```

Please help.
Thanks.

---

UPDATED 2013-03-14 
It's very strange. I found this issue only when the provider and the NFC Activity in the same application. like this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfcdemo"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="build-svn291" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION"
        android:label="@string/provider_label"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name=".provider.DemoProvider"
        android:authorities="demo"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:permission="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />
</manifest>
```

But if I use two separated application, it works will like.

```
<!-- Application Provider -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfcdemo.provider"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="build-svn291" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION"
        android:label="@string/provider_label"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />

    <provider
        android:name=".provider.DemoProvider"
        android:authorities="demo"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:permission="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />
</manifest>

<!-- Application UI -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfcdemo.ui"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="build-svn291" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.client.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    
</manifest>
```